# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que Git se “olvide” de un archivo que fue rastreado, pero ahora está en .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Hay un archivo que Git estaba rastreando, pero ahora el archivo está en la lista .gitignore.

Sin embargo, ese archivo sigue apareciendo en git status después de editarlo. ¿Cómo obligas a Git a olvidarlo por completo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sólo lo quieres [eliminar de la historia actual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached), te serviría:

```
git rm --cached <fichero>
```

De esta manera lo mantendrías en local igualmente. Si quieres eliminarlo de toda la historia de git podrías usar [`filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt---tree-filterltcommandgt):

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm <fichero>'  HEAD
```

---

EDICIÓN:

La opción `filter-branch` está desaconsejada por la propia página oficial de `git`. Si necesitas esa opción más avanzada échale un ojo a [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/).

Comment: Gracias, excelente solución `git-filter-repo` funciono perfectamente.